# document.write inside for loops

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following HTML document

```
<html>
<script>
        function explode() {
                pp = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for(i=0;i<pp.length;i++) {
                    document.write(pp[i].href);
                }
        }
</script>

<body>
 <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
 <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
 <button onclick="explode()">Explode</button>
<body>

</html>
```

When executed I expect all the hyperlinks printed on my window, but I get only the first one. Can someone explain this

**Update**
I am convinced by the answer that `document.write` will reset the page contents, but if it is that so then, I already the list of objects in the variable `pp` and by the end of the for loop I should get the LAST element, why the first element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start writing to the document after it has been completely loaded, you will implicitly open a new document and replace the current document. You can use `document.write` to add to the document while it is loading (i.e. in scripts tags inline in the code), but once the document is complete, using `document.write` will implicitly call `document.open` to create a new document to write to.

The list of elements that you get from the [`getElementByTagName` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a live list, which is updated when elements are added to or removed from the DOM. When you have written the first item to the document the list is empty, as there aren't any matching elements in the document any more.

Comment: That's a clean answer, could you add more links/explanation about `live list`. How come the list gets updated after the script enters the loops. I'm not able to understand the program flow

Comment: _When you start writing to the document_ : after dom ready ( worth to mention that)

Comment: @vikkyhacks: I added a link to the documentation. When you start writing to the document, a new document is opened, so everything is removed from the current document. As the list of elements is live, it will become empty as none of the elements that it did contain exists any more. When your code comes to the condition `i<pp.length` at the end of the first iteration of the loop, `pp.length` will be zero, and it will exit out of the loop after one iteration.

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` -  will clear your browser at first time when he meets `document.write`!

You have to aggregate the values.

Do this

```
  function explode() {
            pp = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            var a='';
            for(i=0;i<pp.length;i++) {
              a+=pp[i].href
            }
       document.write(a);
    }
```

http://jsbin.com/buzexuce/2/edit

To illustrate on the other direction :

```
look what happens here : 

 <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
 <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
 <button onclick="explode()">Explode</button>

  <script>
    var  pp = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                for(i=0;i<pp.length;i++) 
                { document.write(i);}
    </script>
```

[image]

(before dom ready - everything is fine as expected).

Comment: No, the document is not cleared each time `document.write` is called, only the first time. The first write implicitly does a `document.open` which does the actual clearing.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
document.write(pp[i].href);
```

Comment: he asked why he sees it once instead of 2 links.

Comment: he is doing `pp[0]` which is wrong. This is the issue he has asked for.

Comment: _but I get only the first one_ yes. but with the right solution (using `i`) he would get only one last value (always). he needs botyh to fix `i` and aggregate values.