# Display an Object with innerHTML without using a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, innerhtml

I am trying to display the contents of an object without a function. Inside of a for loop with var i as the incrementor, I have a button that when clicked, I want to show all the comment objects for each post.

```
document.write("<button onclick=\"this.innerHTML='"+data.posts[i].comments+"'\">Display Comments</button>");
```

I need it to be done inside this document.write as I have tried using a function but the loop will overwrite the i value and make the button only show a value on the last button.

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283771/document-write-inside-for-loops

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container-element">
</div>

<script>    
    var dynamichtml = "";
    for (var i in data.posts)
     dynamichtml += "<button class='dyn-msg' data-msg='"+data.posts[i].comments+"'>Display Comments</button>";

    $("#container-element").html(dynamichtml)
    $("#container-element").on("click",".dyn-msg",function(){
          $(this).html($(this).data("msg"));
    })
</script>
```